# gnuplot plotting large numbers in exponential format

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am attempting to plot the following graph

### Frame size           Tx Frames/sec       Tx Bytes/sec

```
    64                      14881016            952385024           
   150                       7353006           1102950900
   300                       3906314           1171894200
   600                       2016193           1209715800
   900                       1358759           1222883100
  1200                       1024654           1229584800
  1500                        822432           1233648000
```

using the file

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 1280,960 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'

set ylabel "Ethernet Frame Size"

set xlabel "k"

set title "Ethernet Frame Size vs Transmitted Bytes/Transmitted Frames"

set key reverse Left outside

set grid

set style data linespoints

set output 'ethernet_line_rate_1.png'
plot "ethernet_rate.dat" using 1:2 title "Ethernet Frame Size vs Transmitted Frames"

set output 'ethernet_line_rate_2.png'
plot "ethernet_rate.dat" using 1:3 title "Ethernet Frame Size vs Transmitted Bytes"
```

Which is fine except that I get the graph as below.[image]

Y-axis shows numbers in the exponential format.How do I make it in normal numerical foramt?

Comment: `set format y "%.0f"`

Comment: Format specifiers http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html

Comment: @ rici, you should answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 set format y "%.0f"
```

You can use any printf-style format specifier which would accept a double.